# Genymotion 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, android, genymotion

I just installed Virtualbox, downloaded genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin and tried `chmod +x` and `chmod 777` on it before trying `./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin` within the folder. I get permission denied error as given below

```
bash: ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin: Permission denied
```

I even tried `sudo` before `./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64`

To test my luck, used sudo bash and ran `./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64` as root. Still, no luck.

The Genymotion website says **Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) or above (64bit)** . I however have 14.04.

I did try other guides. But nothing was referring to 2.7.2 of Genymotion with 64 bit 14.04

I have VirtualBox installed already.

Comment: If you have Virtualbox installed, you could run Ubuntu 15.10 or 16.04 in a virtual machine :)

Comment: Thanks @NickWeinberg , is that how it should work ? I am trying to save on resources. Would be hard to run two instances of Ubuntu at the same time. Any work out for using Genymotion within 14.04 ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Genymotion, but my guess is there's a good reason that they specify 15.10 or above. It would not be terribly hard to run two instances of Ubuntu at the same time. Maybe someone else has a solution for you.

Comment: Where you put your downloaded `./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin` file? is it in your Ubuntu home?

Comment: I tried both within a folder and home.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a problem of your Linux OS and Genymotion compatibility,
genymotion 2.7.2 is not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.

Even after you installed the bin file, if genymotion still can't work normally, you have to add a PPA.

Open terminal and type this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```