# PhoneGap installment

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, genymotion

I am trying to install PhoneGap off of this 
link: http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/ and I have a problem. I have gotten to the part where I have to install genymotion. I installed genymotion but my computer can't find the file `chmod u+x genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin`
That was what I typed in and this is what it returned:
`chmod: cannot access 'genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin': No such file or directory`
 So I wondered if I had really downloaded it. I went to my search bar and I typed "genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin" just as it should, it showed me the file. What can I do so that when I perform the actions I am supposed to do (The ones written the link provided) they work (basically how can I fix this error). I know that VirtualBox isn't the error because I have it installed (I entered the code that installs it and it didn't return any errors).

Comment: You need to either change to the directory containing `genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin` prior to running the command or provide the `/full/path/genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin` prior to your `chmod u+x`

Comment: @ElderGeek okay. Once I would have changed the directory, will I just replace the genymotion-2.8.2_x64 to the name I will have changed it to. If I use your seconde example will the code I will type into the terminal look like this `/full/path/genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin chmod u+x genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin`  ?

Comment: Dear @ElderGeek I tried your suggestions and it still doesn't work. I believe the root problem is that the computer doesn't recognise the file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to locate the information regarding installation of genymotion in the link that you provided, be that as it may, in more general terms do the following.

First find the file in question: in your case the command `find / -type f -name "genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin" 2>/dev/null` should be useful.

What this does is search the file system from the root `/` for a file (-type f) with the name `genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin` and redirects all error messages to `/dev/null' sanitizing the output to help eliminate further confusion. You can leave off the`2>/dev/null` part if you don't mind seeing the numerous Permission Denied Errors that you will invariably get as find attempts to traverse your complete file system as a normal user.

Either way, the final line of output will be the full path to the file you wish to change permissions on similar to `/full/path/to/filename.ext` where `/full/path/to/` is the full path to the file in question and filename.ext is the file (in your case genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin)
to
Now as mentioned in my comment you have the option of doing

*A)*

```
cd /full/path/to/
chmod u+x genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin
```

**OR**

*B)*

`chmod u+x /full/path/to/genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin`

Note: You can reduce the possibility of typing errors with *this approach* by copying the full path and filename from the output and pasting it after `chmod u+x`

Either of these approaches  will result in adding [executable permissions for the user who owns the file in question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29589/chmod-ux-versus-chmod-x).

The only other possibilities I can think of is that you thought you downloaded the installation file and didn't (or did and failed to extract the content of it somewhere sensible. For instance you could be looking for the file in your VM installation rather than your host installation where you actually extracted it or vice versa) Either of these would result in the inability to change permissions as you can't change permissions on a non-existent file.

There's a related post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794931/genymotion-2-7-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit) but I doubt that's your issue since you can't seem to find the file at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question . I did what you told me to do and when I entered  ` ./genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin`  it still said no such file or directory. When I tried your option B, nothing happened (I don't know if that's what should have happened).

Comment: This is what the terminal sent me: ` ./genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin
bash: ./genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: @TheodoreTremblot Updated Answer